# Nestjs - Issue with mocha types declared in the @nestjs/microservices dependency

Tags: nestjs

When embedding @nestjs/terminus@6.1.0 in our nestjs project, a type of @nestjs/microservices is not recognized:

$> tsc

```
node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/external/redis.interface.d.ts:2:23 - error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'mocha'.
2 /// <reference types="mocha" />
                        ~~~~~
Found 1 error.
```

When adding **npm i --save-dev @types/mocha**, I obviously get conflicts with Jest which is the testing framework we are using...

$> tsc

```
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts:27:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'beforeEach' must be of type 'HookFunction', but here has type 'Lifecycle'.

27 declare var beforeEach: jest.Lifecycle;
...
```

For now, the only workaround I found was to use skipLibCheck in the tsconfig.json file... not very clean.

Here the dep part of my package.json file:

```
[...]
"dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^6.0.5",
    "@nestjs/core": "^6.0.5",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^6.0.0",
    "@nestjs/graphql": "^6.2.1",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^3.0.2",
    "@nestjs/terminus": "6.1.0",
    "@godaddy/terminus": "4.1.0",
    "app-root-path": "^2.2.1",
    "class-transformer": "^0.2.0",
    "class-validator": "^0.9.1",
    "codacy-coverage": "^3.1.0",
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.5.0",
    "graphql": "^14.3.0",
    "graphql-tools": "^4.0.4",
    "js-cache": "^1.0.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "typescript": "^3.5.2",
    "winston": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/testing": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.0.39",
    "@types/jest": "^21.1.8",
    "@types/node": "^9.3.0",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.4",
    "jest": "^21.2.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.14.1",
    "prettier": "^1.11.1",
    "supertest": "^3.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^21.2.4",
    "ts-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "ts-node": "^4.1.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.1.1",
    "tslint": "5.3.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "lib",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage"
  }
```

Any idea how to fix this in a clean way?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

For those having the same issue, an alternative to the skipCheckLib I found in the [following article](https://medium.com/@elenasufieva/handling-type-declarations-clash-in-typescript-b05b10723f47) is to:

- create a empty file in my project **overrides/mocha/index.d.ts**
- add to the tsconfig file **"typeRoots": ["overrides", "node_modules/@types"]**

This will overrides mocha def and will avoid def duplication (since I am only using Jest).

It's not as clean as I would like but it's still better than the **skipChekLib** option.

Answer (score 1):

We have resolved this issue with the release of `@nestjs/microservices@6.5.1` - sorry for the inconvenience.
https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/2534

Answer (score 0):

You can make your approach work by adding `"types": []` to `compilerOptions` and including all types packages except `@types/jest`. In your case you can use `"types": ["express", "node", "supertest"]`.

Comment: I tried this one but defining mocha `"types": ["express", "node", "supertest", "mocha"]`, but then running my e2e tests (based on Jest) won't work anymore since it will use types of mocha instead of Jest (or won't recognize those proper to Jest).

Comment: Have you tried using multiple tsconfigs? I use tsconfig.build.json that extends tsconfig.js to run tsc, so I put types into tsconfig.build.json.

Answer (score 0):

Same error for me. Since it seemed to be related to the microservices package of NestJS, I've just add "@nestjs/microservices" in my dependencies and now it works fine.

Comment: I also tried this one but it didn't work for me. Are you using Jest as well in your project?

Comment: Yes I'M using Jest, that's odd that it didn't work for you. Maybe you could try to update your packages? I've updated all mine since it's kind of a new project. I see that you're using Jest@21 and they're now at 24, so maybe that'll help.